# Java PKCS11 Standard for Crypto tokens

Tags: java

Hello I am trying to make an applet in Java which reads Smart Cards ( as Security Tokens) and I didn't manage to handle it at all. I already found this :http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunPKCS11Provider which should give me some details... but I have never added a provider in Java ... and  I also can't find any of the classes mentioned there for the provider...

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need to reference the provider directly. You ask the API for a particular algorithm and it finds the appropriate provider. PKCS#11 is quirky, though. You'll have to read the [detailed doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html) very carefully. I strongly recommend writing the app to do something with a software provider first. For example, create a Java Keystore, create a key in it and sign it then verify the signature. Definitely write a positive and negative test case. In other words, show that tampering with the data makes the verification fail. Next, figure out how to use the PKCS#11 provider by changing your program to use it. Using the Java cryptography APIs is hard enough without adding all the complications of PKCS#11 and your specific smart card to the mix.

Comment: Yes I relised that... but is there an example anywhere I could use? as a step by step install guide ... and some details use about it?

Comment: You can take a code example from a wiki like this https://mywiki.ncsa.illinois.edu/wiki/Java_PKCS11 but for setup they are just going to refer back to the provider docs you already have. Don't forget you also need to do some setup particular to your smartcard type. I'd consult the manufacturer's docs and run their demos first of all. That's the joy of working with non-comoddity hardware.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am using Aladdin e-token ... any thoughts on it?

Comment: Sorry, don't know anything about that specific piece of hardware. All I can recommend is split the problem so you can ask more targeted questions. The Aladdin questions might be better targeted at a forum for that manufacturer.

Comment: Hi, managed to read it ... but every time I try to import a certificate I get this :trusted certificates may only be set by token initialization application is there a flag or anything...I need to set ? I get it for every certificate I try to import...

Comment: Even though the Java APIs allow you to import certificates into KeyStore objects, it sounds like the hardware manufacturer chose to not allow that operation through their KeyStore API. They probably have a separate tool. Maybe it is for security purposes or they were just lazy.

Comment: aha ... ok ... do you happpen to also know a sample on how to generate a RSA key pair on the token and sign a CSR with it ? thank you very much for your interest and help.